# find extremum of $y = x(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: derivatives

given function:

$$y = x(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

steps:

$$y'=\frac{(x^2-x)^{\frac{-2}{3}}2x-1}{3}$$

After simplifying:

$$ y' = \frac{2x-1}{(3x^2-3x)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

therefore

$$ x = \frac{1}{2}$$ $$x \ne 0$$

Am I right with calculus?

Comment: I think you have applied the product rule incorrectly. I get the stationary point as $x = 1/4$. Why don't you edit your post to include your working to find $y'$.

Comment: @M.Mass: Assuming the problem statement is correctly written, your first step is wrong. The equation is 

   $$y =  (x) \left((x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$

not

   $$y =  \left(x(x-1)\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: Also, for any critical point, you need to _test_ it to see whether of not it corresponds to a local extreme point.

Comment: And recall: A critical point is a value of $x$ in the domain of the function such that _either_ the derivative is 0, or the derivative doesn't exist. Thus, for this function, you will get critical points at $x = 3/4%$ and $x = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is
$$
f(x)=x\sqrt[3]{1-x}
$$
not
$$
\sqrt[3]{x(1-x)}
$$
at least according to common notation. Thus the derivative is
$$
f'(x)=(1-x)^{1/3}+x\cdot\frac{1}{3}(1-x)^{-2/3}\cdot(-1)=
\frac{1}{3(1-x)^{2/3}}(3-3x-x)=\frac{3-4x}{3(1-x)^{2/3}}
$$
which vanishes at $x=3/4$ and is undefined at $x=1$.

Note that the function is increasing over $(-\infty,3/4]$ and decreasing over $[3/4,\infty)$ (the point where the function is not differentiable doesn't harm).

---

Alternatively, use the fact that $x\mapsto x^3$ is a continuous bijection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, so the function $f$ has the same extremal points as
$$
g(x)=(f(x))^3=x^3(1-x)=x^3-x^4
$$
Since $g'(x)=3x^2-4x^3=x^2(3-4x)$, we get the same conclusions as before.

Comment: samll, but logical mistake in my calculus, thats why I wanted someone to check me, thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

for the first derivative we get by the product rule $$f'(x)=(x-1)^{1/3}+\frac{x}{3\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}$$